# Orange3 concatenate tables with different targets

Tags: orange

I have two input datafiles to use in orange, one corresponds to the train set (with targets "A", "B" and "C") and the other to the unknown samples ( with targets "D" and "E"  to be able to identify the unknown samples in the scatterplot of the two first principal components).

I have applied PCA to the train dataset and through a python script i have reapplied the PCA transformation to the test dataset, however the result have a ? in the target value for all entries in the unknown samples set.

I have tried to merge the train and unknown samples sets with the merge table widget, and apparently it does the same, all samples in train are correct, but the unknown samples have ? as targets.

The only way i managed to have this running properly is to have unknown samples and train set on the same input file. Which is not practical for obvious reasons.

Is there any way to fix this?

Please note that i have tried to change the domain.class_var and the target value directly on the transformed unknown samples, but it also alters the domain of the train dataset. Apparently when the new table is created it just have a reference to the domain of the original train data after PCA.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed it by converting the data into numpy arrays concatenate them and then back to table.

Here is the code if anyone is interested:

```
import numpy
from Orange.data.table import Table
from Orange.data import Domain, DiscreteVariable, ContinuousVariable

trnsfrmd_knwn_data = numpy.array(in_object)
trnsfrmd_unkwn_data = numpy.array(Table(in_object.domain,in_data))

ndx = list(set(trnsfrmd_knwn_data[:,len(trnsfrmd_knwn_data[0])-1].tolist()))[-1] + 1
trnsfrmd_unkwn_data[:,len(trnsfrmd_knwn_data[0])-1] = numpy.array([i for i in range(0, len(trnsfrmd_unkwn_data))]) + ndx

targets = in_object.domain.class_var.values + in_data.domain.class_var.values
dm = Domain([ContinuousVariable(x.name) for x in in_object.domain.attributes], DiscreteVariable('region', values=targets))

out_data = Table.from_numpy(dm, numpy.append(trnsfrmd_knwn_data,trnsfrmd_unkwn_data,axis=0))
```